# To what should I attach the "ajaxStart" method?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'd like to check for the presence of any outstanding Ajax events in a script like the following:

```
$('nav a').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(address,function(){
        //do some stuff when complete
    });
});
```

Now, if the nav is clicked twice, both requests will execute, and I essentially want to prevent this from happening. jQuery offers the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` methods but I don't need to manipulate the DOM so I'm not quite clear on what object to call them on. I was thinking of using a variable instead:

```
var busy = false;
$(busy).ajaxStart(function(){this=true});
// etc...
```

With

```
$('nav a').click(function(){
    if(busy==false){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(address,function(){
            //do some stuff when complete
        });
    }
    else return false;
});
```

But:

1. Is it legal?
2. Is there a simpler/more straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: By "legal" I mean "in accordance with acceptable syntax". Basically, are you allowed to wrap any variable in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of doing this in javascript is the following:

```
(function() {
    var buzy = false;
    $('nav a').click(function(){

        if (buzy) return;
        buzy = true;

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(address,function(){
            //do some stuff when complete
            buzy = false;
        });
    });
}());
```

To answer the original question, `ajaxStart` could be bound to `document`:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    buzy++;
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    buzy--;
});
```